# If "A" Then "Textfield"

Tags: search

i am using Sharepoint 2013.

A person can choose between 3 options. 
Option A, Option B and Option C. 
If the person choose Option B, only then there will be a text field (and then the person must type a text in it)

I use only Sharepoint 2013 and Nintex.
I hope you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar things to this in custom forms (I don't use Nintex so I am not sure if that has inbuilt functionality for this)l
Use Javascript to change visibility of fields based on the option/logic as required.

Add your own custom validation when you click commit.

Quick sample below (which is called with an Onchange event handler):

```
function newspaperChecked(){
if(document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl43_g_5136254b_f6b3_4aec_9e86_dbfe68a5dba7_ff461_ctl00_ctl02').checked)
{
    document.getElementById("NewsPaperMessage").style.visibility = "visible";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("NewsPaperMessage").style.visibility = "collapse";
}
```

}

Your commit/save button will want to call a custom function where you then validate the field.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I must realize it without Javascript. We are learning the basics of Sharepoint in school and we must realize it with a if Condition or something else. Is that possible?

Comment: Not that I am aware but I am fairly new to SP my self. As you are using Nintex might be best to go to their forums to see how to do this.